# How to insert a linked list into another linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to write a function that allows me to insert a linked list into another linked list at a certain position such that if the linked lists were:

```
list1: [1]->[2]->[3]->NULL
list2: [4]->[5]->[6]->NULL
```

Then calling the function:

```
insertList(list1, list2, 1);
```

modifies list1 such that:

```
list1 = [1]->[4]->[5]->[6]->[2]->[3]->NULL
```

and list2 remains unmodified and usable.

Here is struct definition:

```
struct _node {
    int item;
    struct _node *next;
}


struct _list {
    struct _node *head;
    struct _node *last;
}
```

Here is my attempt, which does not work because I get seg fault.

```
void insertList(struct _list *list1, struct _list *list2, int pos) {
    assert(list != NULL && list2 != NULL);

    int currPos = 0;
    struct _node *curr = list1->head;

    if (pos < 0 || pos >= numLines(list1)) {
        abort();
    }

    // traverse linked list to get to correct position
    while (curr != NULL && currPos != pos) {
        curr = curr->next;
        currPos++;
    }

    struct _node *temp = curr->next;
    curr->next = list2->head;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    curr->next = temp;

    // updating last
    curr = list1->head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    list1->last = curr;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Does every `head` point to the same node, or can there be different heads? Do you update every `head` for `list2` because it's now a part of `list1` since you're only copying pointers instead of data? And where is the code that updates the `tail` pointer(s) for `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: I thought i have to keep list2 untouched so its pointers remain unmodified because it has to remain usable after the function is called.

Comment: Your `node` structure has conflated two things — the nodes in the middle of the list (`item` and `next`) and the overall start and end of the list (`head` and `last`).  To maintain consistency, every time you add or remove an item from the head or tail of the list, you have to step through the entire list to update the `head` and `last` pointers.  When you do the insertion of one list into another, you have to update all the pointers in the inserted list to point to the head and tail of the list into which it is inserted.  Etc.  Separate the two sets of data.

Comment: @user6005857 You're already modifying `list2`. For example, given your call `insertList(list1, list2, 1);` you're modifying the `[6]` in `list2` to connect it to the `[2]` in `list1`. This means that when you look at the `[6]` in `list2` after the function call, its `next` field will point to `[2]`, not `NULL`. In other words, you're modifying `list1` and `list2` with the code above, not just `list1`. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune no I would like to keep list2 unmodified. Does this mean I need to clone it and use the clone of list2 instead of list2 itself?

Comment: @user6005857 Yes, that's exactly what I meant. You'd still need to fix your `insertList` function, but you're one step closer to getting what you want. I highly suggest thinking about @JonathanLeffler's comment to make things easier for you -- one head and one tail, instead of N heads and N tails, where N is the number of items in the list. Then you could do something like `insertList(list1, cloneList(list2), 1);` and use the `head` and `tail` fields of the lists to greatly simplify the function -- no need to walk the entire list. :-)

Comment: Ok I will do that. Thank you. I will separate head and tail into a different struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (curr != NULL) {
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

--> At this position `curr` is `NULL` and then you do

```
curr->next = temp; //NULL->next gives you seg fault.
```

You might want

```
while (curr->next != NULL){
 ... 
 }
```

You also will have to change the last part

```
 while (curr != NULL) {
    curr = curr->next;
}
list1->last = curr;  //here also curr is NULL, you need to rull the loop
                     //till curr->next!=NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get seg fault after making these changes.

Comment: For what inputs do you get seg fault?The same as mentioned in the problem?

Comment: Same inputs in example.